# Rearranging an array using for loop in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a 1 x 15 array of values:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

I need to rearrange them into a 3 x 5 matrix using a for loop:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it doesn't seem you rearranging the string but inserting something into it?

Comment: i need 1-5, 6-10 and 11-15 in different subsequent rows. This is for Matlab.

Comment: Then add the `Matlab` tag (and get rid of `loops` and `for-loop`).

Comment: Do you **have** to use a `for` loop?  This can easily be done using `reshape`

Comment: @Dominik The OP has an array defined in MATLAB and wishes to rearrange the elements so that they're in matrix form.  The OP didn't place any tags in his/her post, which caused confusion.  I see that the appropriate tags have been placed.

Comment: @rayryeng yeah man there was nothing in here when I first saw this. Glad it's more clear now ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to show you three methods.  One where you need to have a `for` loop, and two others when you don't:

## Method #1 - `for` loop

First, create a matrix that is 3 x 5, then keep track of an index that will go through your array.  After, create a double `for` loop that will help you populate the array.

```
index = 1;
array = 1 : 15; %// Array we wish to access
matrix = zeros(3,5); %// Initialize
for m = 1 : 3
    for n = 1 : 5
         matrix(m,n) = array(index);
         index = index + 1;
    end
end

matrix =

  1     2     3     4     5
  6     7     8     9    10
 11    12    13    14    15
```

## Method #2 - Without a `for` loop

Simply put, use `reshape`:

```
matrix = reshape(1:15, 5, 3).';

matrix =

  1     2     3     4     5
  6     7     8     9    10
 11    12    13    14    15
```

`reshape` will take a vector and restructure it into a matrix so that you populate the matrix by columns first.  As such, we want to put 1 to 5 in the first column, 6 to 10 in the second and 11 to 15 in the third column.  Therefore, our output matrix is in fact 5 x 3.  When you see this, this is actually the **transposed** version of the matrix we want, which is why you do `.'` to transpose the matrix back.

## Method #3 - Another method without a `for` loop (tip of the hat goes to Luis Mendo)

You can use `vec2mat`, and specify that you need to have 5 columns worth for your matrix:

```
matrix = vec2mat(1:15, 5);

matrix =

  1     2     3     4     5
  6     7     8     9    10
 11    12    13    14    15
```

`vec2mat` takes a vector and reshapes it into a matrix of as many columns as you specify in the second parameter.  In this case, we need 5 columns.

Comment: My stubbornness about `.'` is bearing its fruits! :-D

Comment: a tip about `reshape`,  writing : `matrix = reshape(1:15, 5, []).';` will assign automatically the right dimension, and as such is similar to vec2mat.

Comment: @natan Actually `vec2mat` also fills missing values (although that doesn't seem necessary here): `vec2mat(1:7,3)`

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of (bsx)fun, here is another option...

```
bsxfun(@plus,1:5,[0:5:10]')

ans =

 1     2     3     4     5
 6     7     8     9    10
11    12    13    14    15
```

less readable, maybe faster, but who cares if it is such a small of an array...

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ] ;
A = reshape( A' , 3 , 5 ) ;
A' = 1     2     3     4     5
     6     7     8     9    10
    11    12    13    14    15
```

Comment: I already used `reshape` as part of my answer.  However, good twist in transposing the array and swapping the dimensions.