# Matrix Max Value in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

I have a 111 x 48 Matrix called "TEMP"
How do i find the max value in "TEMP"?

max(Temp);

compares all the values in first column and returns the entire row of 48 values. I only need 1 value (highest value) in the entire Matrix.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
max(Temp(:))
```

.. will unravel Temp into a vector, then give you the single largest value.

Of course,

```
max(max(Temp))
```

works too.

Comment: `max(Temp(:))` looks like a smile given as a parameter :)

Comment: You need to *wink* `;`  at it to suppress the *smile*

Comment: I always thought `(:)` was the body of a snowman. Wishful thinking, I guess. @user3698120 - If this answer helped you, you should consider accepting it by clicking the green check mark to the left.

Comment: @user3698120 Accept my answer too while you're at it!  I answered your question a couple of days ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026341/rearranging-an-array-using-for-loop-in-matlab

Answer (score 1):

`max(max(TEMP))` is what you are looking for. `max(X)` returns max value from vector X. If X is matrix, then returns vector of max values in each row. so `max(max(TEMP))` will return max value from matrix. Expressions  `sum(sum(X))`, `min(min(X))` works the same.